# How to use ng-model with condition in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am using angular to perform CRUD on my apis in my admin panel.

I have below screen shot which is **dashboard-payment.html**

[image]

HTML snippet for above SS is :

```
<div class="MT10 clearfix">
          <h2 class="FL MT15">Manage Payment Gateway List</h2>
            <button class="FR"><a href="" ng-click="go('/manage-payment/',routeParamsAppId)">Create New Payment Gateway</a></button>
        </div>
        <div class="MT10" ng-init="initPaymentController()">
          <table width="100%" class="tbl_data">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Gateway Name</th>
                <th>App ID</th>
                <th>App Key</th>
                <th>App Secret</th>
                  <th>Is Active</th>
                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="detail in paymentDetails">
                <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio"></td>
                <td>{{detail.name}}</td>
                <td>{{detail.appId}}</td>
                <td>{{detail.appKey}}</td>
                <td>{{detail.appSecret}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"></td><!--go('/manage-CMS/',detail)-->
                <td width="20"><a href="" class="icon edit" ng-click="go('/manage-payment/',detail)"></a></td>
                <td width="20"><a href="javascript:;"  ng-click="removeGateway(detail,$index)" class="icon delete"></a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Then onclick of "**PENCIL**"(edit functionality) icon I am calling one function in my controller whose code is :

```
$scope.go = function (path, obj) {

        if(obj.appId == undefined){
            $location.path(path +obj);
        }
        else{
            $location.path(path + ""+obj.id + "/"+obj.appId);
        }

    };
```

Here I am passing my entire data object in order to display already entered details in textbox.

So after click on **PENCIL** I can view following in my browser:
[image]

If you observe url :

http://127.0.0.1:59232/index.html#/manage-payment/9b276b15-7460-4bf0-a62d-66d92f222fe4/5538e1c3e4b0f4eb7d13fd08

**parameter : 5538e1c3e4b0f4eb7d13fd08** is getting set to **APP** textbox as needed, which is disabled meaning can not be edited.

Uptil this everything is fine. Now i have covered EDIT scenario.

Now in **dashboard-payment.html** you can see **CREATE NEW PAYMENT GATEWAY** button is there.

Now on click of that button I am displaying below SS:

[image]

Now URL looks like:
**http://127.0.0.1:59232/index.html#/manage-payment/5538e1c3e4b0f4eb7d13fd08**

and i want to display that **5538e1c3e4b0f4eb7d13fd08** parameter in my **APP** textbox. But i am struggling to display that.
My HTML snippet for that is : **manage-payment.html**

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <div class="MT10" ng-init="getPaymentDetailsById()"><!--getPaymentDetailsById()-->
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> Name:</label>
                <span class="rightside">
                        <input type="text" value="" ng-model="singleGatewayDetails.name" >
               </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> APP :</label>
            <span class="rightside">       
                <input type="text" value=""  ng-model="paymentDetails.id" ng-disabled="appId">
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> APP KEY:</label>
              <span class="rightside">       
                  <input type="text" value=""  ng-model="singleGatewayDetails.appKey" > 
              </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> APP SECRET:</label>
              <span class="rightside">       
                  <input type="text" value=""  ng-model="singleGatewayDetails.appSecret">
              </span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

What I can say is is displays that parameter while editing but does not displays while posting new data.

Please help.

Comment: Question is a bit long and difficult to read. Any way you could simplify it?

Comment: @AlexMA what i want is how to use same textbox with 2 different scenario ?

Comment: there is no way to know by watching on templates only

Comment: @skazska I have added both templates and its code

Comment: @mahendrakawde

despite of :

    The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of   ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

it is ok if it suitable for you.

looks like initPaymentController()  works correctly,  but    getPaymentDetailsById()   -  may not      angular  try  to be silent of error  and often if you do not see values there a some error in script  

show  or  audit function getPaymentDetailsById()

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that you use [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) to manage moving between your webpages? instead of using java script to move between the webpages.

This will help you to deal with the two separate scenarios (Create and Update) much more easily, as you will have separate controllers and can call separate templates or initialize the values differently.

It took me about 1/2 hour to get going with ng-route but I have found it has speed up my development enormously.

Comment: I am using ng-route to route between pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some values from an url to be available in models you may need to use angular-route,  or $location services.